Searching for highest alphanumeric value in Excel after matching text strings
if i have a table as such

how can I search for the values in Column C in column A, then lookup the values in column B, and if there are multiple matches, then lookup the highest alphanumeric  value
the values that are being lookup in Column B are alphanumeric INC00123 or INC0012345, where INC0012345 is higher than INC00123 .
so to summarize I need to
1-search for a text string in a column
2-take matches and lookup values in their adjacent cell, But.
3-there could be multiple matches, for which I want the highest values to be returned in the look-up, but.
4- the values are alphanumeric, and don't have a set number of characters
so the end result would be

not sure how to do that

If it returns the 'highest' alphabetical string in column B when there are multiple matches, shouldn't it return INC00123 for REF00012?

If you have Office 365 you could use:
=TRIM(VLOOKUP("* "&C1:C4&" *",SORT(" "&A1:B5&" ",2,-1),2,0))
It searches for the string to be present in range A1:B5, sorted by the values of  B1:B5 and returns the value of B1:B5.
Since I wanted to search for the string as part of the whole cell value I added a space and a wildcard (*) prior and after the search string as well as the lookup range, to exclude false positives. Therefore the return value would include the leading and trailing space character, hence the use of trim to remove them again.

Another Office 365 solution:
=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(FILTER($B$2:$B$6,ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&C2&" ",$A$2:$A$6))),1,-1),1)



thanks to you both , both solutions work
